# How have both local and remote variable inside an SSH command

Tags: linux, bash

How can I have both local and remote variable in an ssh command? For example in the following sample code:

```
A=3;
ssh host@name "B=3; echo $A; echo $B;"
```

I have access to A but B is not accessible.

But in the following example:

```
A=3;
ssh host@name 'B=3; echo $A; echo $B;'
```

I don't have A and just B is accessible.

Is there any way that both A and B be accessible?

Comment: Looks like A is accessible in the 2nd and not B.  Is this right?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
A=3;
ssh host@name "B=3; echo $A; echo \$B;"
```

---

**When you use double-quotes**:

Your shell does auto expansion on variables prefixed with `$`, so in your first example, when it sees

```
ssh host@name "B=3; echo $A; echo $B;"
```

bash expands it to:

```
ssh host@name "B=3; echo 3; echo ;"
```

and **then** passes `host@name "B=3; echo 3; echo ;"` as the argument to `ssh`. This is because you defined `A` with `A=3`, but you never defined `B`, so `$B` resolves to the empty string locally.

---

**When you use single-quotes**:

Everything enclosed by single-quotes are interpreted as string-literals, so when you do:

```
ssh host@name 'B=3; echo $A; echo $B;'
```

the instructions `B=3; echo $A; echo $B;` will be run once you log in to the remote server. You've defined `B` in the remote shell, but you never told it what `A` is, so `$A` will resolve to the empty string.

---

**So when you use `\$`, as in the solution:**

`\$` means to interpret the `$` character literally, so we send literally `echo $B` as one of the instructions to execute remotely, instead of having bash expand `$B` locally first. What we end up telling `ssh` to do is equivalent to this:

```
ssh host@name 'B=3; echo 3; echo $B;'
```

Comment: You can check the generated command follows `A=3; ssh -v host@name "B=5; echo $A; echo \$B;" 2>&1 | grep -A 2 'Sending command'` or `sh -xc 'A=3; ssh host@name "B=5; echo $A; echo \$B;"'`.

Comment: Note that this can delay variable expansion, too. `ssh host@name 'B=\$(find . -name "*.txt"); echo \$B'`