# 'grep' not recognized over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, openssl

I'm trying to close my app remotely like that:

```
ssh pi@192.168.0.227 "kill $(ps aux | grep '[M]yApp' | awk '{print $2}')"
```

It fails and prompts:

> grep : The term 'grep' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

If I login via SSH first and then do the command, it works, but I need it to be one-liner. I've set `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` variable `PermitUserEnvironment` to `yes`, and tried to use full path to grep (`/bin/grep`), and even removed spaces around the pipe (these were all answers to questions similar to mine) but nothing allows me to pass the command. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is expanded by your local shell before being passed to the other host. Since it is a double-quoted string the command within `$()` runs *on your local host.* The easiest way to pass such a command to a remote host is with a "quoted" [here document](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument):

```
ssh pi@192.168.0.227 <<'EOF'
kill $(ps aux | grep '[M]yApp' | awk '{print $2}')"
EOF
```

Similar: [How have both local and remote variable inside an SSH command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13826149/96588)